# NSArray to NSData for Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I need to save array in core data, so i read that I can use NSData for it. So I think that I have problem with archiving.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSData *newData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newArray];
[myEntity setValue:newData forKey:@"nameOfMyData"];
```

And then I try to pick my array in another VIewController for filling

```
NSData *newdata = [NSData dataWithData:self.myEntity.nameOfMyData];
NSMutableArray *photoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
photoArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:newdata];
```

I have no crash, but in command line appear next:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; 
did you forget to send -  finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?
```

And when i try to add object to my array, it does not add

```
[photoArray addObject:myImage];
```

So myImage is creating and with it I have no trouble, but in debugger always write for photoArray:

```
photoArray = (NSMutableArray*) 0x00000000 0 objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. But when unarchiving the array rather use:

```
NSData *newdata = [NSData dataWithData:self.myEntity.nameOfMyData];
NSMutableArray *photoArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:newdata]];
```

You either have objects in your array that dont conform to NSCoding protocol or you do not save your core data context (or saving is unsuccessful).

After archiving with

```
NSData *newData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newArray];
```

what do you see when you check newData for nil? I suppose it is nil.

Comment: Thanks, now i can save myImage to PhotoArray =) But now i must to save my entity, so it's trouble. Can i make some method in singleton for saving entity? Because i have some ViewControllers and take entity from the first ViewController

Comment: The question is unclear. You retrieve an entity from your core-data managed objects context and make a change to it. Then you save your context. On retrieving it again (elsewhere) it will contain the changes. Whether you handle core-data access using a singleton or not depends on your implementation.